# Dynamically injected script execution not working on page navigation using <svelte:head>

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

In my test application using Sveltekit, I tried to inject third party scripts to page using

```
<script>
     let scriptsData = 'console.log("Some script executed")';   
</script>
<svelte:head> 
    {@html
        `<script>${scriptsData}</script>`     
    }  
</svelte:head>
```

The above code works fine on direct hit of the page but not during manual navigation to the page. The same thing work if I use

```
<svelte:head> 
   <script>console.log("Some script executed")</script>`     
</svelte:head>
```

But I wish to add scripts dynamically per page. I read somewhere that browser for safety reasons will not execute scripts added dynamically. It accepts only sanitised one's.Is there any easy workaround

Answer (score 0):

If the script is loaded in +layout.svelte, the behavior is expected.
It's a one-way system unless you make it dynamic. However, if you've loaded the script in a dynamic page and you're still encountering this issue, there's a way to address it.

```
<script>
import { page } from '$app/stores'
let userScript = `console.log('Path: ${$page.url.pathname}')`
userScript = `<script>${userScript}<\/script>`;
</script>
<svelte:head> 
 {#key $page.url.pathname}
   {@html userScript}
  {/key}
</svelte:head>
```

I guess this applies for both pages.